# Recurrence evaluation at specific index

Tags: difference-equations, index

I have the following set of equations. I want to solve a[n] and f[n] for the indices n=1:5. Note that the relation a[2n+2] involves the derivative of f[2n] and the relation for f[2n+2] involves the derivative of a[2n]. The first four statements are starting conditions.

1. a[0] == function(z) --> for simplicity lets take z^6
2. f[0] == function(z) --> for simplicity lets take z^6
3. a[2n+1] == 0
4. f[2n+1] == 0,
5. a[2n+2] == (1/((2n+3)^2 -1))(-k^2 a[2n]-(((2n+3)(D[a[2n],{z,2}]))-2 omega D[f[2n],z])/(2n+1))
6. f[2n+2] == (1/((2n+3)^2 -1))(-D[f[2 n],{z,2}]-(1/(2n+1))((2n+3) k^2 f[2n]+2k D[a[2 n], z]/c))

Can anyone help ?

Thanks in advance

Jim

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 2):

Basically we just put your definitions directly into Mathematica.  The only change we have to make is to solve for `n` given `2n + 2` (which I'm calling `m`).

```
a[0] = C[1][z]; (* The C[_] are just placeholder functions *)
f[0] = C[2][z]; (* I would have used a and b or f and g, but... *)
a[_?OddQ] := 0;
f[_?OddQ] := 0; 
a[m_?EvenQ] := 
 Block[{n = 
    m/2 - 1}, (1/((2 n + 3)^2 - 1)) (-k^2 a[
       2 n] - (((2 n + 3) (D[a[2 n], {z, 2}])) - 
        2 omega D[f[2 n], z])/(2 n + 1))];
f[m_?EvenQ] := 
  Block[{n = 
     m/2 - 1}, (1/((2 n + 3)^2 - 1)) (-D[
        f[2 n], {z, 2}] - (1/(2 n + 1)) ((2 n + 3) k^2 f[2 n] + 
         2 k D[a[2 n], z]/c))];
```

You can get your desired result with

```
a /@ Range[5]
f /@ Range[5]
```

$$
\begin{align}
a(1)&=0 \\
a(2)&=\frac{-k^2c_1(z)+2 \omega  c_2'(z)-3
   c_1''(z)}{8} \\
a(3)&=0 \\
a(4)&=\frac{3 c k^4 c_1(z)+2 k \left((7 c k-2 \omega ) c_1''(z)-6 c k
   \omega  c_2'(z)\right)-12 c \omega  c_2{}^{(3)}(z)+15 c c_1{}^{(4)}(z)}{576 c}
   \\
a(5)&=0
\end{align}
$$
$$
\begin{align}
f(1)&=0 \\
f(2)&=-\frac{3 c k^2 c_2(z)+2 k c_1'(z)+c c_2''(z)}{8 c} \\
f(3)&=0 \\
f(4)&=\frac{15 c k^4 c_2(z)+2 k \left(6 k^2 c_1'(z)+(7 c k-2 \omega )
   c_2''(z)+6 c_1{}^{(3)}(z)\right)+3 c c_2{}^{(4)}(z)}{576 c} \\
f(5)&=0 \\
\end{align}
$$

To substitute your functions (both $z^6$):

```
a /@ Range[5] /. {_C -> (#^6 &)} // FullSimplify
f /@ Range[5] /. {_C -> (#^6 &)} // FullSimplify
```

$$
\begin{align}
a(1)&=0 \\
 a(2)&=-\frac{1}{8} k^2 z^6+\frac{3 \omega  z^5}{2}-\frac{45 z^4}{4} \\
 a(3)&=0 \\
 a(4)&=z^4 \left(\frac{35 k^2}{48}-\frac{5 k \omega }{24 c}\right)+\frac{k^4
   z^6}{192}-\frac{1}{8} k^2 \omega  z^5-\frac{5 \omega  z^3}{2}+\frac{75 z^2}{8}
   \\
 a(5)&=0 \\
\end{align}
$$
$$
\begin{align}
 f(1)&=0 \\
 f(2)&=-\frac{3 k z^5}{2 c}-\frac{3}{8} k^2 z^6-\frac{15 z^4}{4} \\
 f(3)&=0 \\
 f(4)&=\frac{k^3 z^5}{8 c}+z^4 \left(\frac{35 k^2}{48}-\frac{5 k \omega }{24
   c}\right)+\frac{5 k z^3}{2 c}+\frac{5 k^4 z^6}{192}+\frac{15 z^2}{8} \\
 f(5)&=0 \\
\end{align}
$$

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes it does ! Thank you very much.